# Jasmine : prioritise test files execution order

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, puppeteer

I have a big issue in Jasmine, i can't find a way to prioryze my test files, in fact the test files are executing in alphabetical order:

I have something like this :

- file_test_1.js
- file_test_2.js
- ...
- file_test_n.js

I want to do something like this for the execution of my tests without renaming my tests files:

- file_test_2.js
- file_test_1.js
- ...
- file_test_n.js

Is there a way to specify to Jasmine a priority for the files containing the tests ?
(Sorry for my bad english).

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to set a specific order of file execution but I know there is a way to run the tests in random within a file. Not sure if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks you Mansour, but that not what i'm looking for :)